# Does a void expression has no value?

Tags: c#

From C# in a Nutshell

> **Expressions and Operators**
>
> An expression essentially denotes a value.
>
> ...
>
> **Void Expressions**
>
> A void expression is an expression that has no value. For example:
>
> ```
> Console.WriteLine (1)
> ```
>
> A void expression, since it has no value, cannot be used as an operand
>   to build more complex expressions:
>
> ```
> 1 + Console.WriteLine (1)      // Compile-time error
> ```

1. Since a void expression is an expression, it must denote a value.
   But how can it "has no value"?
2. Since a void expression has no value, is a void expression a
   statement?

Thanks.

---

After reading the answer from Eric Lippert to [Can a C# lambda expression ever return void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029433/can-a-c-sharp-lambda-expression-ever-return-void), as pointed out by Rufus L in a comment, I have the following questions:

- Is a call to a method always an expression, whose value is the value returned by the method?
- is a void expression always an invocation of a method which returns void?

Comment: Statements and expressions can be thought of as syntactical constructs and void as something at the type level. So the flaw here is “since X is an expression, it must denote a value” – that’s only true when the expression doesn’t produce void. (2) is only true insofar as all expressions are statements.

Comment: Check the answer from @Eric Lippert to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029433/can-a-c-sharp-lambda-expression-ever-return-void

Comment: @RufusL Thanks. (1) Is a method with a `return` statement always an expression, whose value is the value returned by `return` statement in the method? (2) is a void expression always an invocation of a method which `return` void?

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. Except that void expressions don't *"return void"* - they don't `return` at all. But I think that's what you mean.

Comment: @RufusL What i asked in (2) in my last comment is: is a void expression always a call to some method which returns void? I am not talking about whether a void expression returns void, but whether the method that it calls returns void.

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 4):

> Since a void expression is an expression, it must denote a value. But how can it "has no value"?

The statement is false. An expression need not "denote a value".

Most expressions do.  Some do not. In particular:

- expressions classified as "nothing" because they are invocations of void-returning methods
- in, say `System.Console.WriteLine("")` we have the expression `System` which denotes a namespace, not a value, and the expression `System.Console` which denotes a type, not a value.
- in `x[1] = 123;` , `x[1]` denotes a *variable* or a *set accessor*, not a *value*.
- In C# 7 you can now use `throw` in a context where an expression is expected, but it does not have a value.

And so on. There are a number of expressions which do not denote values; can you think of more?

Albahari is just making a simplification for pedagogic purposes. For an exact definition of how expressions are evaluated, read the specification.

> Since a void expression has no value, is a void expression a statement?

No.

> Is a call to a method always an expression, whose value is the value returned by the method?

Yes, assuming that the method returns a value.

Exercise: List all the ways in which a method call can *not* return a value.

> is a void expression always an invocation of a method which returns void?

Yes.

> What is the difference between " a method which doesn't return a value" and " a method which returns void"?

A method which returns void does not return a value. But there are non-void methods which do not return a value. Can you write one?

> "a call to method which doesn't return a value isn't an expression"

That statement is false. All method calls are expressions regardless of whether they return a value.

> a call to a method which returns void is a void expression

That's correct.

You really should read the specification. It is precise.

Comment: Thanks. (1) What is the difference between " a method which doesn't return a value" and " a method which returns void"? (2) from your reply, it seems that "a call to method which doesn't return a value isn't an expression", while " a call to a method which returns void is a void expression".